# is there any solution pandas memory error?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 10**9

df_csv = pd.read_csv('RESULT2.csv', error_bad_lines=False,nrows=chunksize)
print(df_csv)
```

this is my code when i run the code i got this error log

```
Killed
```

actually the csv file is 32GB which is the biggest one
i used python in linux

also before run the code i typed

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

this command

so.. is there any solution to fix it

Comment: How much ram does your machine have? Here are some really great tips on how to choose chuck_preprocessing and datatype filtering to help process large data sets such as this one: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-pandas-with-large-data-9594dda2ea4c

Comment: that is 32GB ...

Comment: A CSV of 1GB is going to be larger in memory since that will not be represented as a single bytestream buffer, but as a multitude of individual Python objects such as strings and arrays and so on, each of which takes more memory than the raw data they contain. Try with a smaller file and see the expansion factor.

Comment: actually i know that but i need to way to read that file so.. is there any way to read all of them?

Comment: Buy more memory or stream in the data instead of trying to tackle this in one big chunk.